# Get value from an input select with getBounds

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, leaflet, bounds

I have an input select (or select box, whatever), with some values, examples: 72, 73, 74...
Where each value is an area on a map. I need that value for each option selected, so as to zoom in on the map in the respective area of that value. I tried the following code:

```
$("#numSearch").on('change', function(e) {

        var value = $(this).find(':selected').val();
        //var boundArea = value.target;
        //map.fitBounds(boundArea.getBounds());
        alert(value);

    });
```

Where $("#numSearch") select's id.

The result is the select's values (72, 73, 74...) as a string type.

And this:

```
//var boundArea = value.target;
//map.fitBounds(boundArea.getBounds());
```

Doesn't work :(

Can somebody help me zoom in on a selected area according to the value selected in the select???

Comment: You should be able to do `var value = this.value`.  But that may not address your zooming issue.

Comment: The way you're calling `this` would be mapping to the block scope of the anonymous function declaration, not the global scope.  Have you tried `e.target.value`?

Comment: Correction to my last comment - jQuery does map $(this) to the global scope, since $ is declared in the global scope.

Comment: Elton, can you please provide a bit of the GeoJSON for your data?

Comment: Sure! My geoJSON is this: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/eltonsantos/leaflet-tests/master/teste3/js/geoSetoresComerciais.js

Comment: I continue without can it :/

Comment: @IvanSanchez Can you help me, please?